# 12VDC 3500mA filtering, what are voltage regulators and capacitor values

Tags: power-supply, voltage, capacitor, voltage-regulator, power-filtering

I have a 12VDC 3500mA power supply and I would like to filter the outgoing voltage from any noise. My plan is a simple scheme:
output from the power supply -> capacitor -> voltage regulator -> capacitor -> ...

And I would like to ask what capacitors should I use, and what voltage regulator. I was thinking about 7812 only that it will limit the current to 1000mA which I would not want. What would you advise, or maybe I should do it some other way?
I want the output voltage to be as stable as possible and also not to lose too much current.
And the power supply I use is the Meanwell RT-65B

link to its datasheet:
https://modularsynthlab.com/Download/RT65B_Datasheet.pdf?v=9b7d173b068d

Thank you in advance

Comment: Before trying to filter the noise, you should first know what kind of noise the stuff you want to power can tolerate. What noise frequencies is it sensitive to? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to reduce noise. No, you can't remove all noise, sorry.

Your Meanwell supply is a switching converter so you can expect substantial noise (ripple, mostly) from it. In fact the datasheet specifies 120mVp-p which is quite a lot for audio use.

Using a regulator like the 7812 would help but remember that it needs more input voltage to work. In fact it need more that 2V to work properly so you'll need at least 14V to do that. The basic idea however is correct and you often see in designs a switching pre-regulator and a linear regulator at the end.

Your best bet for this project is to use a low pass Pi filter like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMgdb0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is completely passive and it's mostly limited by L1 current handling and the capacitor voltage rating.

Search around for low pass pi-filter resources, it's quite popular; if needed you could even chain more cells but it's trickier to design

Comment: Worth noting that, depending on the application and frequency spectrum of the output ripple / noise you may need filters with both relatively large electrolytic capacitors for the low frequencies and smaller film or ceramic ones for the high frequencies.

Comment: For the typical switching noise (on good supplies) you only need ceramics usually. I had more issues with noise due to the *supplied* circuit insufficient distributed capacitance